# How to split two words from a one textbox and put it into two seperate texboxes

Tags: vb.net

How do I split two words in a single textbox and put the first word in textbox number 1 and the second word in textbox number 2 when I clicked the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Click
    Dim words = txt1.Text.Split()
    txt2.Text = words(0).Trim()
    If words.Length <> 1
        txt3.Text = words(1).Trim()
    End If
End Sub
```